# Converting input to list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am doing something like this

```
    read_line_to_codes(user_input,Li1),nl,
    write(Li1),nl,
    atom_codes(A,Li1),
    write(A),nl
```

So I am getting this output-

```
|: 'hello',18,19,'Bye'

 [39,104,101,108,108,111,39,44,49,56,44,49,57,44,39,66,121,101,39]
 'hello',18,19,'Bye'
```

But I want a list having this-`L=['hello',18,19,'Bye']`
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In **SWI-Prolog**you can use `atomic_list_concat/3` with the first argument (a list) uninstantiated, the second argument the separatorn (`','` in your case) and the third argument the atom you already have (`A`). Note that this use of `atomic_list_concat/3` is not portable

E.g.:

```
   atomic_list_concat(L, ',', A)
```